# Can't create extensions for Postgres

Tags: ruby, postgresql, postgis

I'm using postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5 with my Rails (4.0.1) app and Ruby (2.0.0-p451), and one of the migrations looks like:

```
class CreateExtensions< ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
        extensions = %w(fuzzystrmatch hstore plpgsql postgis postgis_tiger_geocoder postgis_topology)
        ext_query = extensions.map {|e| "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS #{e};" }.join
        connection.execute(ext_query)
    end
end
```

Whenever I try to run the migration file I get the following error:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS fuzzystrmatch;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_tiger_geocoder;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology;
PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS fuzzystrmatch;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_tiger_geocoder;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology;
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS fuzzystrmatch;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_tiger_geocoder;CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology;
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:435:in `block in log'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:430:in `log'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
    from (irb):14
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I installed Postgres using Homebrew, Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you install PostGIS?

Comment: yes I did using homebrew and I have postgis-2.1.4_1 already installed.

Comment: @NickVeys, do I need to install a different version? Thanks for your willing to help

Comment: You installed PostGIS via Homebrew and you had it already installed?  Everything I've seen on this error indicates PostGIS is not properly installed.  Nothing to do with Rails or Ruby.

Comment: You are right @NickVeys, once I removed PostGIS and reinstalled it through Homebrew it worked. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have PostgreSQL and PostGIS installed from the same sources and with compatible versions.